# android 4.4.2 - cannot read files in /data/data/(classname)

Tags: android, permissions

I want to develop apps on a Samsung Note 10.1 tablet, running Android 4.4.2. Discovered I cannot read files in /data/data/(classname I'm using) after installing my APK.  Google searching says one can "root" one's device but this sounds risky at best (might brick your system).  Found a 'better' way: after opening a shell, via "adb shell", do "run-as (class name)".  However, "run-as (classname)" is yielding "package (classname) is unknown". (note: I contacted Samsung technical support but they could not help me.) Really need to be able to get into my /data/data/(classname) area and be able to do "adb push" and "adb pull" from there to do development and testing. Any and all suggestions are welcome.  TIA.

Comment: " However, "run-as (classname)" is yielding "package (classname) is unknown"" -- `run-as` takes your `applicationId` (defaults to your `package` attribute in the manifest), not a Java class name.

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I'm using - the package attribute from the manifest.  Sorry that I described it wrong in my question above.

Comment: Meant to add - my packages.list file is rw-rw----, but apparently needs to be rw-rw-r--.  Don't know if this is android 4.4.2 bug only or samsung bug.  Need to flash factory image of android 4.4.2?  Saw may be '8kb bug' too -i.e., run-as reads only first 8kb of packages.list.  If yours is past 8kb can't find it.  Any one can verify? Would have to delete apps which doesn't sound good. Will flashing of 4.4.2/newer fix this?  Any other way? TIA.